Django Project, browser not making HTTP GET request for static files in development server
Hello I’m trying to load my static files to my templates but they’re not getting passed to my browser. When I look at the developer tools, I don’t see my Javascript and HTML files being passed to the browser. For some reason when I make a request for the page that I'm trying to include the static files on, I get 'GET /login/ HTTP/1.1'.
The browser isn't even making a request for the static files. When I enter in the URL for the static files such as domain/static/styles.css or domain/static/index.js, I get sent to the file and no issue occurs. It’s just for some reason when I enter the page that the static files should be included on, browser doesn’t make a request for the static files.

Impossible to troubleshoot without seeing some code.  Your template, maybe urls.py, maybe file structure.  Are you running this on a development server or in production?
